# Creating static utility methods should not be overused however ? how to avoid it?

Tags: java, oop, static

With the time ...lots of utility method are introduced in java project for more complex and simple task.

When using static methods we introduce tight coupling in our code and it make our code more difficult to test, especially if the utility methods are quite complex.

I am just thinking that it now difficult to manage and test these utilities. please guide me in avoiding these utilities methods and how can i organize existing project to remove all STATIC utilities.

Can you help me avoiding static method ?

Comment: I really don't see how using `static` methods increases coupling and makes testing difficult.

Comment: @NPE: You can't mock or override static methods. Code which makes use of static methods can thus be hard to test.

Comment: @TomAnderson you've got is the wrong way around. It's the fact that static methods are stateless that makes then easy to test

Comment: @Bohemian: No. Read my comment again. Static methods may well be easy to test, but code which uses them is often not.

Comment: @TomAnderson Both [JMockit and PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/jmockit/wiki/MockingToolkitComparisonMatrix) are capable of mocking `static` methods.

Comment: @Jeffrey just because there is a workaround doesn't make it less problematic

Comment: @JensSchauder You call it a workaround, I call it a solution.  There were times when an interface was needed for mocking.  So should every method be in an interface, or do you use "workaround" frameworks that can mock non-interface methods?

Comment: @JensSchauder Yes, but it's not as big an issue as he was originally making it out to be.

Comment: @herman Yes I do use PowerMock occasionally, when I have to work with legacy code. But I also know it is a really bad code smell. I also use static methods, but as soon as I feel the urge I refactor to normal objects as described in my answer, or if the static method is not under my control, I create a wrapper object.

Comment: @JensSchauder I was talking about ordinary Mockito: it can mock classes, no interfaces needed.  But earlier frameworks couldn't, so I'm sure there were (and still are) people who say that "classes without interfaces are bad".

Comment: @herman I do use workaround frameworks as Mockito, but I consider it more a workaround for the verbosity of Java.

Comment: @herman: As a data point, there are indeed still people who think that you should never mock classes, only interfaces, and that JMock's inability by default to mock classes is therefore a good thing. I know this because i work with a couple of them. It goes without saying that they are quite mad.

Comment: @NPE here is answer why ,http://wiki.c2.com/?ClassicOoAntiPatterns static method in service layer , is bad for me , example 1) i tried use cacheable with spring and looks its not supported because cacheable is using proxy pattern which cant be applied to static methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To contradict the other answers currently available: **Static methods are bad!**

They do introduce strong coupling. Yes there are cases where it is acceptable. Yes you can make a seam for inside a static method, by making the strategy used inside exchangeable. But as a rule of thumb static are still bad.

To answer the question, how to get rid of static methods. Simple: put them on a proper Object. All statics are gone. Have we improved our code? not much yet. If we replace

```
callToStaticMethod()
```

with

```
new X().callToNoLongerStaticMethod()
```

we replaced a static call with a constructor call which is essentially just another static method. But now your `X` is just another dependency, so you can inject it:

```
class A{
    private final X x;
    A(X aX){
        x = aX;
    }
}
```

Note: there is no need to use Spring or any other framework for this. If you feel like it provide a constructor which uses the default implementation. If you are a purist, introduce an interface for X.

Testing `A` without relying on the implementation of `X` becomes trivial and obvious. Same for replacing `X` in any way.

Comment: OK, go tell the java API designers that they should remove `java.util.Collections`, `java.util.Arrays`, `java.lang.Math`, ...  People who think static methods are bad should be banned from using these :-)

Comment: Imagine having to use inject an `ArrayToListConversionStrategy` everytime you wanted to call `Arrays.asList(...)`

Comment: Thanks @Jens : This is something i was looking for.

Comment: @herman I doubt anybody would listen to me. That's why I prefer Scala. No static there and nice tools to avoid the boiler plate code Java forces on you when you try to write conceptually clean code. :-)

Comment: @JensSchauder but Scala has singleton objects to provide the role of static methods, and singletons are (by purists) regarded as much of an anti-pattern as static methods.  (disclaimer: I'm a Scala novice)

Comment: @herman objects are a little better  because they can implement interfaces, so the transition is a little smoother. The tools I were referring to are mainly functions and much less verbose constructors.

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing wrong with having lots of static methods.

Static methods are (or should be, read on) [stateless](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_%28computer_science%29), which makes them the easiest methods to test - there's no setup, just call them.

You don't need mocking, because there is no state to deal with.

Regarding being stateless, technically static methods can be stateful if they use static variables to store state. If this is the case, from a good-design perspective they should be converted to instance methods using instance variables to store state, employing the singleton pattern if required.

Comment: static, stateless methods are easy to test. But testing code that uses these static stateless methods is hard, because they can't be mocked easily. Replacing them with instance methods in injectable components allows mocking the component and injecting the mock in tests.

Comment: Actually in code-base ,there are lots of static method..which are playing with state of objects ...like taking  Object as input and returning updated Object .....thinking in OOPs, I wanted to move these methods to class itself.

Comment: @JBNizet I suppose I was thinking about utilities that have only one implementation, so injection isn't necessary or helpful - the methods just "do stateless, contextless stuuf". Your comment is very good though.- highlighting that if your static methods change behaviour with context, strongly consider injection and instance methods.

Answer (score 1):

Static utility methods are not so bad. You can hide a package-private strategy behind the static call. This can be easily tested (and replaced) given that the test case belongs to the same package. Moreover, it makes the code very readable. Of course, the clients of the static utility method can still only use one implementation in their tests. So here is some inflexibility.

Bohemian is right when talking about state. If your static utilities have state you are doing something wrong.

About your question: If you want to avoid static methods you can use the spring framework and define different implementations of utilities that you use and test in different contexts. In this case, however, access to these objects is not so convenient as you must first obtain a reference to the context that knows your utility *object*.

Comment: You're missing the whole point of Spring. You don't need a reference to the Spring context to get a reference to a bean. You just need to have it injected by Spring where you need it. It's as simple as `@Inject private UtilityObject utility`.

Comment: Yes you can lessen the pain caused by static methods, but they are still bad. Also Spring is in no way needed to get rid of static methods.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with a set of static utility methods that belong together in a class.  See for example `java.util.Collections`.  If every method in that class that operates on a `List` would be specified in the `List` interface itself, they would have to be implemented by all subclasses.  As long as they can be implemented by the public `List` methods, there is no problem.

Of course, as soon as you start adding methods to the interface (or in case of a class, making methods public) only to be able to put functionality in static methods instead of the class itself, then you're on the wrong path.

Comment: What you describe are weaknesses in the language, which might make static methods the smaller of two problems. But statics are still a problem.

Comment: @JensSchauder What weakness in the *language* did I describe?

Comment: That a method of the List interface has to get implemented by all its implementations/subclasses, causing either code duplication or a rigid inheritance hierarchy. Scala traits solve this problem quite nicely, as demoed in Scala´s collection API and the ease with which new implementations are added, although the interfaces have a lot more methods then the Java equivalents.

Comment: For the record, Java 8 will have defender methods, which allow interfaces to have concrete methods. We'll thus be able to call `list.sort(comparator)` instead of `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`.

Comment: @JensSchauder I see what you mean and that Scala (and JDK8) feature is great.  But in case of 3rd party code, you won't be able to extend the interface anyway (could be another language weakness, but the question is about Java): see **guava**'s Collections2 class.  I do agree it's not a good idea to put e.g. DAO code in static methods because of the tight coupling.  But I've never felt the urge to mock e.g. `Collections.sort()`, `String.valueOf()`, `Arrays.asList()` or `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.*`.  I guess  it relates to the mockist/classicist approach to testing.

Comment: I agree: In the cases you describe the need of mocking them is rare or not existing. But unfortunately this is not the case in the average static method I have seen in the past.

Comment: @JensSchauder Are you sure these qualify as static **utility** methods (which is what the question and this answer was about)?  A method that performs a DB query or a web service call doesn't IMHO.

Comment: AFAIK utility basically means "something useful", which might be anything.